# Cronmonitor with import-html

Tags: theming, importing-exporting, cron

So I'm trying to get the import-html module to import files every time there is a cron run. However, I was hoping someone could help me understand what the format of file_list, profile_id, and source_siteroot is supposed to be. Below is my interpretation of file_list and source_siteroot

```
function cronmonitor_cron() {
  if(variable_get('cronmonitor_enable',0)){
    $file_list = ".";
    $context = array();
    $context['profile_id'] = drush_get_option(array('profile-id'), import_html_current_profile_id());
    $context['source_siteroot'] = "sites/default/files/old-sites/.";
    import_html_import_files($file_list, $context);
  }
}
```

but whenever I run cron, I get

```
invalid argument supplied for foreach() import_html_process.inc:52
```

This in turn is the line

```
foreach ($file_list as $list_index => $rel_path) {
```

Which definitely means there is something from with $file_list, right? What should its structure be?
The site says it is 
"an  array of simple file paths, probably selected from the file_list form.
 *   Relative to the import context settings."

But it'd help if someone gave me an actual example as the words go over my head right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed $file_list to an actual list, ["."] and source_siteroot to "sites/default/files/old-sites/" and that gave me a valid path. Also profile_id to import_html_current_profile_id();

Thanks!